# Independence in infinite sequence of random variables

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I was reading [this page](http://planetmath.org/monotoneclasstheorem) from planetmath. It states the following,

> Consider an infinite sequence of independent random variables
>   $\{X_n,n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Using the Monotone Class Theorem one can
>   show, for example, that any event in $\sigma(X_1,X_2,…,X_n)$ is
>   independent of any event in $\sigma(X_{n+1},X_{n+2},…)$.

where $\sigma(X)$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$.

Can anyone suggest a source for rigorous proof of this assertion? Thanks.

You can see some other details (though not required) from the link, Example 1.

Comment: Please make the question self-contained instead of relying on some off-site material.

Comment: I am asking for the proof of the above assertion, it is simple and concise and does not require off-site material. I added that $X_i$'s are random variables, and $\sigma$ notation denotes the $\sigma$-algebra if this is required.

Comment: At the moment, it does require off-site material (for example, if $X_n=X_1$ for every $n$ and if $X_1$ is not degenerate then the assertion does not hold).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Is it OK now?

Comment: Sure, the question is self-contained now.

Comment: @Mark The proof on planetmath seems quite complete. What is not clear?

Comment: @n.c. I am a sort of beginner. In the proof, it says "Now it is clear that the sets A which satisfies the above relation form a monotone class." or "A second application of the theorem shows". But I am not sure how the theorem is applied rigorously.

Comment: I have the same problems in understanding that are described in this old question.